# Probability of Photoelectric and Campton decrease as photon energy increases, WHY?

Tags: energy, photons, photoelectric-effect, interactions, matter

Why Probability of Photoelectric and Campton decrease as photon energy increases??

Comment: Were you thinking about [compton scattering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compton_scattering)? Please mention your prior research; it doesn't look too nice when you get one of the keywords wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rate of interaction of a photon with normal matter depends on
a matrix element, which derives from the integral of the product of
the electron and photon wavefunctions.   The orbitals of electrons
in atoms are on the scale of the Bohr radius, 529 nm.   For any
wavelength of light shorter than that, one can expect that the
oscillatory light wavefunction will alternate from positive to negative
more rapidly than the electron wavefunction does, and
that means the matrix element sums to... zero.

Thus, a downward trend  is expected with increasing energy; photon
energy is inversely proportional to photon wavelength.

The outer electrons (largest volume) are thus out of the picture at
modest photon energies (a few dozen eV), and even inner electrons
have little effect on gamma rays (tens of thousands of eV).

Other interactions, as with nuclei, dominate at the highest
photon energies.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, It helped me a lot...God bless you